# What is the prescribed duration of breast feeding?

Tags: sunnah, food, children

What is the prescribed duration of breast feeding a child in light of Quran and Hadith?

Comment: You should breast feed your child for nearly 2 years. Stop brest feeding a month before the child turns two.

Comment: When his / her first teeth start to grow. It can be before he is two. I don't know if there is a hadith about it but every woman will tell you this is the definite sign you should stop.

Comment: I am looking for an answer in light of hadith. Please let me know if you know the reference. Coz all i have heard is 2 years, so wanted to know what the hadith mentions. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walaikum salammm warahmatullahi wabarakatuh,

Allaah has enjoined breastfeeding in His Book, when He said (interpretation of the meaning):

> “The mothers shall give suck to their children for two whole years, (that is) for those (parents) who desire to complete the term of suckling”
>
> [al-Baqarah 2:233]

https://islamqa.info/en/20759